# How to pass a struct parameter using TCOM in Tcl

Tags: com, tcl

I've inherited a piece of custom test equipment with a control library built in a COM object, and I'm trying to connect it to our Tcl test script library.  I can connect to the DLL using TCOM, and do some simple control operations with single `int` parameters.  However, certain features are controlled by passing in a C/C++ `struct` that contains the control blocks, and attempting to use them in TCOM is giving me an error `0x80020005 {Type mismatch.}`.  The struct is defined in the .idl file, so it's available to TCOM to use.

The simplest example is a particular call as follows:

C++ .idl file:

```
struct SourceScaleRange
{
    float MinVoltage;
    float MaxVoltage;
};
interface IAnalogIn : IDispatch{
...
    [id(4), helpstring("method GetAdcScaleRange")] HRESULT GetAdcScaleRange(
        [out] struct SourceScaleRange *scaleRange);
...
}
```

Tcl wrapper:

```
::tcom::import [file join $::libDir "PulseMeas.tlb"] ::char
set ::characterizer(AnalogIn)  [::char::AnalogIn]
set scaleRange ""
set response [$::characterizer(AnalogIn) GetAdcScaleRange scaleRange]
```

Resulting error:

```
0x80020005 {Type mismatch.}
    while executing
"$::characterizer(AnalogIn) GetAdcScaleRange scaleRange"
    (procedure "charGetAdcScaleRange" line 4)
```

When I dump TCOM's methods, it knows of the name of the `struct`, at least, but it seems to have dropped the `struct` keyword.  Some introspection code

```
set ifhandle [::tcom::info interface $::characterizer(AnalogIn)]
puts "methods: [$ifhandle methods]"
```

returns

```
methods: ... {4 VOID GetAdcScaleRange {{out {SourceScaleRange *} scaleRange}}} ...
```

I don't know if this is meaningful or not.

At this point, I'd be happy to get any ideas on where to look next.  Is this a known TCOM limitation (undocumented, but known)?  Is there a way to pre-process the parameter into an appropriate format using tcom?  Do I need to force it into a correctly sized block of memory via binary format by manual construction?  Do I need to take the DLL back to the original developer and have him pull out all the struct parameters?  (Not likely to happen, in this reality.)  Any input is good input.

Comment: You could try to pass a bytearray with the size of 2 floats (8 bytes), e.g. `set scaleRange [binary format x8]`

Comment: Tried; did not work.  Neither did `set scaleRange [binary format f2 {0.0 0.0}]`.  Still trying things...

Comment: FWIW, at this point I believe that this is a COM/tcom limitation, and I'm going to have to learn enough COM to write a new interface with all single params.  I hope I can get tcom to convert a returned array of floats into a list, or the entire effort is wasted.

Comment: It has taken me all this time to completely implement my system (well, with 2 weeks off for Christmas), but I plan to post a full answer showing the necessary COM dance I went through.  It was not a lightweight solution.